# How to clean workspace of Azure Data Factory using task of Azure Devops?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-functions, azure-data-factory

I want to clean Azure Data Factory workspace before deploying my dev environment to it, How can i clean the workspace using task of Azure DevOps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imo, the easiest way is to arrange a dedicated resource group for your instance of ADF and perform deployment using a **Complete** mode. 
In this case:

> Resource Manager deletes resources that exist in the resource group
>   but aren't specified in the template.

Therefore, no separate task needed for this, but the deployment of ARM template is to be set to a right mode.

In such case, avoid of placing the other objects, like keyvault or storage account in that group, since they will be wiped out during the deployment of data factory.

**References:** [Azure Resource Manager deployment modes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/deployment-modes)